# How can I move an entire <div> that contains images that are positioned using absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css, image, positioning, absolute

[image]

I know having to view an img link might suck, but please help. I really do need it.

The picture posted contains what I want to achieve, however I want to be able to move the entire collage by just having to command the `<div>`. Although, right now, I am able to move the images but that includes having to change the absolute positioning individually every time I have to add something above the image collage. Also, the images need to stack over each other in a particular order. This is my code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #dbdbdb;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.title-holder {
  background-color: #333333;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 7rem;
  padding-bottom: 7rem;
}

.photo-holder {
  height: 60rem;
  background-color: #333333;
}

.pic {
  width: 20%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}

.pic:hover {
  z-index: 15;
  width: 22%;
}

.camera {
  right: 24rem;
  top: 30.5rem;
  z-index: 3;
}

.coffee {
  top: 14rem;
  right: 25rem;
  z-index: 7;
}

.flower {
  right: 38rem;
  top: 42rem;
  z-index: 6;
  width: 22rem;
}

.plane {
  top: 25rem;
  right: 40rem;
  z-index: 4;
}

.plane:hover {
  width: 25%;
}

.wing {
  left: 25rem;
  top: 15rem;
  z-index: 5;
}

.bike {
  left: 20rem;
  top: 32rem;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dosis:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<section>
    <div class="name-holder">
        <h3>Mohd Yusuf Patrawala</h3>
    </div>
</section>

<div class="title-holder">
    <h1>Those Things that make me fall in Love.</h1>
</div>

<div class="photo-holder">
    <img class="pic bike hvr-grow" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
    <img class="pic coffee hvr-bounce-in" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
    <img class="pic flower hvr-bounce-in" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
    <img class="pic plane hvr-bounce-in" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
    <img class="pic wing hvr-grow" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
    <img class="pic camera hvr-grow" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help if the images' sources were not to files on your local hard drive, but to images on the internet. You can use a service like https://placeholder.com/ or https://dummyimage.com/ or upload the image using the editor here on Stack Overflow and use the imgur.com address provided by that.

Comment: @HereticMonkey https://www.pexels.com/photo/person-in-blue-denim-jeans-and-black-leather-shoes-standing-beside-black-and-silver-motorcycle-5192248/      https://www.pexels.com/photo/white-flower-on-a-white-background-4467127/  https://www.pexels.com/photo/person-holding-a-cup-of-cappuccino-1691924/ https://www.pexels.com/photo/airplane-window-view-of-mountains-5274440/ https://www.pexels.com/photo/crop-person-with-retro-reflex-photo-camera-4199722/ https://www.pexels.com/photo/white-passenger-plane-flying-over-the-city-during-sunset-3769532/  These are the links. Thnks for helping a nube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to give the `.photo-holder` div `position: relative` style and position the images accordingly.
The originally shared HTML code had one dangling `<section/>` tag.
`border-radius` should be 50% instead of 100%(but it does not make any visible difference).

You can now move all the images at once only by playing with **`top` and `left` properties on `.photo-holder`**

Open the code snippet in full-screen mode for better visibility.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #dbdbdb;
    font-family: "Dosis", sans-serif;
    font-size: 4rem;
}

.title-holder {
    background-color: #333333;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 7rem;
    padding-bottom: 7rem;
}

.photo-holder {
    height: 60rem;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #333333;
}

.pic {
    width: 25%;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.pic:hover {
    z-index: 15;
    width: 35%;
}

.camera {
    left: 65%;
    top: 65%;
    z-index: 3;
}

.coffee {
    top: 35%;
    left: 65%;
    z-index: 7;
}

.flower {
    left: 50%;
    top: 65%;
    z-index: 6;
}

.plane {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 4;
}

.wing {
    left: 35%;
    top: 35%;
    z-index: 5;
}

.bike {
    left: 35%;
    top: 65%;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dosis:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<section>
    <div class="name-holder">
        <h3>Mohd Yusuf Patrawala</h3>
    </div>
</section>

<div class="title-holder">
    <h1>Those Things that make me fall in Love.</h1>
</div>

<div class="photo-holder">
    <img class="pic bike hvr-grow" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
    <img class="pic coffee hvr-bounce-in" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
    <img class="pic flower hvr-bounce-in" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
    <img class="pic plane hvr-bounce-in" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
    <img class="pic wing hvr-grow" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
    <img class="pic camera hvr-grow" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Group all the images in a div and use margins with positive and negative values, This will help!

Answer (score 0):

Elements with `position: absolute` are in fact positioned *relative* to the last ancestor element that has a `position` attribute.

Thus, the following would solve your problem:

```
.photo-holder {
  height: 60rem;
  background-color: #333333;
  position: relative;
  top: 123px;
  left: 456px;
}
```